# php change value to 0 from any number

Tags: php

guys

I don't know why but php convert my value into 0 each time.

So, i have video table.
Inside i have a row called like and dislike.
Lets say i have 10 dislike.

Every time i check previously value like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE video_id = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $like=$row['vid_like'];
        $dislike=$row['vid_dislike'];
```

and i echo dislike i got 10 in return

Just after that i do that for increase dislike:

```
$dislike1= $dislike +1;
echo "dis = {$dislike1}";
$sqla = "UPDATE video SET vid_dislike='$dislike1' AND vid_like='$like' WHERE video_id = '$id' ";
mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);
```

my echo result is 11. But when i check table after that query, my dislike value is set to 0...

Comment: UPDATE query doesn't use AND like that. Need to use comma.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, these queries are vulnerable to SQL injection. If you want to know more, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) may be useful.

Comment: Your query should be `UPDATE video SET vid_dislike='$dislike1', vid_like='$like' WHERE video_id = '$id' ";` note `,` in place of `AND`

Answer (score 0):

Your update query is not well formatted.

It must look like this :

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
```

[See documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Here you wrote "AND" instead of a comma, which is by the way useless in this case since the second part is `vid_like='$like'` where `$like` value didn't change.